# how series.shape and series.ndim etc. works on complex (difficult) arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

**I am learning python (numpy) arrays, and can't understand following type of arrays:**

In[]

```
B = np.array([
    [
        [12, 11, 10],[9, 8, 7],
    ],
    [
        [6, 5, 4],[3, 2, 1]
    ]
])
```

---

In[]

```
B.shape
```

Out[]

```
(2, 2, 3)
```

(2 r, 2 c, 3 ?)

---

In[]

```
B.ndim
```

Out[]

```
3
```

3?

Answer (score 1):

1. the first list contains `2` sublists `[[12, 11, 10], [9, 8, 7]]` and `[[6, 5, 4], [3, 2, 1]]`

   ```
   [
       [[12, 11, 10], [9, 8, 7]],
       [[6, 5, 4], [3, 2, 1]]
   ]
   ```
2. each sublist contains `2` sublists (ex:`[12, 11, 10]` and `[9, 8, 7]`)

   ```
    [[
        [12, 11, 10],
        [9, 8, 7]
    ], [
        [6, 5, 4],
        [3, 2, 1]
    ]]
   ```
3. each sublist contains `3` ints  (ex : `12`, `11` and `10`)

   ```
    [[[
        12,
        11,
        10
    ], [
        9,
        8,
        7
    ]], [[
        6,
        5,
        4
    ], [
        3,
        2,
        1
    ]]]
   ```

---

With the `numpy` methods

- there is 3 dimensions given by `ndim`
- the size of these dimensions are `2, 2, 3` given by `shape`

Answer (score 1):

Here `B.shape` returns `(2,2,3)`.

In `.shape`:
Integers at every index tells about the number of elements the corresponding dimension has.

According to your array:`[[[12, 11, 10],[9, 8, 7],],[[6, 5, 4],[3, 2, 1]]]`, `[12, 11, 10],[9, 8, 7]` these 2 are inside one list. Similarly, these 2 are inside the main list. Hence it returns: 2 - There are 2 lists inside the main list, then 2 - There are another 2 list inside each list, then 3 - there are 3 elements inside each list.

`B.ndim` will return the number of dimensions of the array. It is basically number of elements in `B.shape` returned tuple. That is why it is 3.